# How to handle missed quiz answers in Telegram bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Imagine that the bot you created sends a poll, and you want to handle a case when the user does not answer anything. As I already know, there is no upcoming update after this case, so the question is: **How to handle it?**

Comment: Are you using the python-telegram-bot module?

Comment: No, I'm coding on Java using TelegramLongPollingBot technique

Comment: After sending the question you can implement a thread which times out after x seconds and send a message to the user. If the answer comes before the thread can be terminated. In the python-telegram-bot you can schedule a message after X seconds, this makes it a bit easier, in the Java lib I dont know if you have similar capabilities.